# ASP.NET Core MVC : one view cannot be found even though it exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have web app which is working, and only one view is creating me a problem.

That view can not be found even if though it exists in the correct folder:

[image: Error]

[image: View it is called correctly]

[image: Created in correct route]

Comment: Check the csproj - the fact that `EditSister.cshtml` is the only one with a child element (denoted by the expansion icon to the left of the filename) makes me think something went wrong

Comment: Nothing happen with that expansion when I had click.

Comment: Check the .csproj file to see if there's any reference to that file (there shouldn't be)

Comment: it exist `<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="Views\FarmAccounting\EditSister.cshtml" />
  <None Include="Views\Shared\AdminLTE\_Scripts.cshtml" />
 </ItemGroup>` but I didn't create there...

Comment: You can safely remove all those `None Include`. Recompiling the project after should fix the problem. Those are sometimes added by VS depending on how you create the files

Comment: Very strange, now it works, after restart VS. But I'm always creating on same way the views with R#... Thanks

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - worth adding as the solution.

Comment: @CakeorDeath I would, if the OP posts enough details for my answer to make sense :) I only guessed from the image and past experience

Comment: How I can help you ? :)